# Как правильно задать :before для всех элементов?

Tags: css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть такой header к примеру.Как видите там в активной части сайта есть оранжевый `border`.

Но вот в чем проблема как мне задать один `before` для всех элементов шапки то есть не пришлось дублировать для каждого элемента шапки псевдоэлемент `before` все занимали ту ширину которую содержит текст

```css
 .list-item {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-bottom: $null; // position: relative;
    width: 60%;
}

.item {
  letter-spacing: 0.3px;
  opacity: 0.9;
  text-align: left;
  cursor: default;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit !important;
    cursor: pointer;
}
a:before {
    content: "";
    width: 7%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 11%;
    z-index: -1;
}
a.active:before {
    contet: "";
    border-bottom: 8px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list-item">
 <li class="item"><a class="link active" href="index.html">Main</a></li>
 <li class="item"><a class="link active" href="javascript:void(0)">Project</a></li>
 <li class="item"><a class="link active" href="javascript:void(0)">News</a></li>
 <li class="item"><a class="link active" href="javascript:void(0)">About us</a></li>
 <li class="item"><a class="link active" href="javascript:void(0)">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нужно ограничить действие `position:absolute` родительским элементом, для этого у ссылки нужно задать `position:relative`.

Так как теперь позиция будет рассчитываться от родителя можно изменить расчет `top`, а так же `witdh`.

Расположение можно считать *снизу*, то есть `bottom`, значением можно установить как раз ширину границы, в данном случае `8px`, и чтобы элемент спустился вниз, значение должно быть отрицательным - `-8px`.

С шириной все проще, так как элемент теперь ограничен родителем - то можно установить ширину `100%`.

Пример:

```css
.list-item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-bottom: $null; // position: relative;
  width: 60%;
}

.item {
  letter-spacing: 0.3px;
  opacity: 0.9;
  text-align: left;
  cursor: default;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit !important;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}

a:before {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  border-bottom: 8px solid orange;
  bottom: -8px;
  width: 100%;
}

a.active:before {
  content: "";
}
```

```html
<ul class="list-item">
  <li class="item"><a class="link active" href="index.html">Main</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a class="link active" href="javascript:void(0)">Project</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a class="link active" href="javascript:void(0)">News</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a class="link active" href="javascript:void(0)">About us</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a class="link active" href="javascript:void(0)">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: а я думал что вы Javascript-ер :) спасибо

Answer (score 4):

`position: absolute` занимает всю область родителя, у которого `position` не `static`. Зададим `position: relative` для ссылки, и изменим `width` и `top` для псевдоэлемента

```css
 .list-item {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-bottom: $null; // position: relative;
    width: 60%;
}

.item {
  letter-spacing: 0.3px;
  opacity: 0.9;
  text-align: left;
  cursor: default;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit !important;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
}
a:before {
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}
a.active:before {
    border-bottom: 8px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list-item">
 <li class="item"><a class="link active" href="index.html">Main</a></li>
 <li class="item"><a class="link active" href="javascript:void(0)">Project</a></li>
 <li class="item"><a class="link active" href="javascript:void(0)">News</a></li>
 <li class="item"><a class="link active" href="javascript:void(0)">About us</a></li>
 <li class="item"><a class="link active" href="javascript:void(0)">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```